# @CompileStatic an entire package?

Tags: groovy

I noticed that Groovy's `@CompileStatic` annotation allows for annotating an entire package.

So I create a package-info.groovy file in the `com.somepackage` package which contains this:

```
package com.somepackage
```

So far so good.  Now I add the annotation:

```
@CompileStatic
package com.somepackage

import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
```

and suddenly Eclipse flags line 2 as an error: "Groovy:[Static type checking] - Unimplemented node type @ line 2, column 9"

What does this mean?  Can I apply static compilation to an entire package this way or I have to continue annotating each individual class in the package as `@CompileStatic`?

Comment: while not what you have asked, I find it easier to set the whole app to CompileStatic and then use CompileDynamic where needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy's `CompileStatic` does not support operating at the package level.  See [this discussion](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/CompileStatic-at-package-level-td5717463.html).  I have opened [GROOVY-7453](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7453) to correct this.

You can use a [config script](http://groovy-lang.org/dsls.html#compilation-customizers) with [Maven](http://groovy.github.io/GMavenPlus/compile-mojo.html#configScript) or [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/2.1/release-notes#groovy-compiler-configuration-script-support), but this would apply CompileStatic to the entire project, not just a single package.  Unfortunately, I think there's no way to do for an entire package, except by annotating all the classes in the packages :(

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will have to give that a shot.  Do you happen to know if tagging classes/methods where I do use Groovy's dynamic features as `@CompileStatic(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)` is respected?

Comment: Yeah, that's an alternative -- make everything static except where you mark it dynamic.  FYI, you can use `@CompileDynamic` as a [shortcut](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/CompileDynamic.html) for that.

Comment: The ticket was closed as fixed, altho that fix appears to just be removing the misleading documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Groovy compiler config script, you can add CompileStatic AST Transformation to every classes of a package and its subpackages.

First create the config script and name it `groovycConfig.groovy` :

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode
import static org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.builder.CompilerCustomizationBuilder.withConfig

withConfig(configuration) {

    source(classValidator: { ClassNode cn -> cn.packageName.startsWith("com.myapp.mypackage") }) {
        ast(groovy.transform.CompileStatic)
    }

}
```

Then tell gradle to use it while compiling groovy

```
compileGroovy {
    groovyOptions.configurationScript = file("groovycConfig.groovy")
}
```

**References :**

- Gradle [GroovyCompileOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompileOptions:configurationScript) documentation
- Groovy documentation : [Compilation customizers](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#compilation-customizers)